# Why doesn't my program catch an exception from dereferencing a null pointer?

Tags: c++, exception

Can some please explain why this exception isn't caught.

```
try {
    // This will cause an exception
    char *p = 0;
    char x = 0;
    *p = x;
}
catch (...) {
    int a = 0;
}
```

When I run the program it dies on the line *p = x.  I would expect that the catch block would cause this exception to be ignored.

I'm using the Qt Creator (2.2) with Qt 4.7.2 compiling with Visual Studios 2008 on Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: This is not an exception. Exceptions are [thrown](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/). You are dereferencing a null pointer, hence the segmentation fault.

Comment: Sounds like you're expecting Java's `NullPointerException`. No such luck here. Now if only there was a `catch(segfault)`...

Comment: @glowcoder: That would be too easy... ;-)

Comment: There is in a way. It's called signal handler.

Comment: I do come from a Java background, and I was hoping something like that was applicable here.  I see __try, but that's only for Windows, is there a cross platform solution or Qt based solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structured exception handling __try and __catch will catch system faults, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Is there an equivalent on other operating systems?  Does Qt provide a cross platform solution?

Answer (score 10):

There is no C++ exception being thrown here. You are causing *undefined behavior* because `*p = x` derefences a pointer with a null pointer value.

An exception is only propogated when you, or code you call, executes a `throw` expression. *Undefined behaviour* is not usually `catch`able.

Comment: Technically, since the behavior is undefined, there *could* be an exception. But there could be an earthquake as well, and the program would still conform...

Comment: @AlexandreC.: True. Both could happen.

Answer (score 3):

Dereferencing a NULL pointer is undefined behaviour. In general, this will trigger a processor trap, and an OS level error. This may then be mapped to a signal, such as `SIGSEGV`, or to an Access Violation error, or it may abort your program, or do anything else.

On Windows, it is mapped to a "structured exception", which is a different beast to a C++ exception. Depending on how you've got MSVC configured, you may be able to catch this with `catch(...)`, but not always.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [`/EHa`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) compiler option to switch on the (Microsoft compiler [specific](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft-specific_exception_handling_mechanisms)) feature which will enable SEH ([Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) exceptions (which is what your null access triggers) to be catchable by `catch(...)`.

Having said that, I wouldn't recommend using `/EHa`.  Better to use the [`__try/__except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) extension or the [SEH API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680659%28VS.85%29.aspx) directly and keep your handling of "structured" exceptions separate from handling of C++ exceptions.  Why ?  Because C++ exceptions are just another perfectly legitimate well defined control flow mechanism, but most things which trigger SEH exceptions are likely to indicate your software has entered the realm of undefined behaviour and really the only sensible thing to do is exit gracefully.  Using /EHa leads to this vital difference becoming unnecessarily blurred.

Answer (score 3):

If you want that you need to write a pointer test:

```
template<typename T>
inline T* ptr_test(T* test)
{
    if (test == NULL)
    {    throw std::runtime_error("Null Exceception");
    }
    return test;
}
```

Then your code looks like this:

```
try
{
    // This will cause an exception
    char* p = 0;
    char  x = 0;
    *ptr_test(p) = x;  // This is what java does.
                       // Fortunately C++ assumes you are smart enough to use pointers correctly.
                       // Thus I do not need to pay for this test.
                       //
                       // But if you want to pay for the test please feel free.
}
catch (...) 
{
    int a = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not caught because its not an exception - nothing is throwing.  You're accessing null/unallocated memory which causes a segmentation fault which is a signal from the operating system itself.

Signals can only be caught by signal handlers, exceptions will not help you with those.

Exceptions only really help in areas where something might call throw(), like a library throwing an exception when you cause a divide-by-zero with the parameters you provided it.

Answer (score 1):

All you're doing right now is dereferencing a null pointer, it is not an exception.

If you want this code to catch something, you have to throw something first. Say, something like:

```
try {
    // This will cause an exception
    char *p = 0;
    char x = 0;
    if (p == 0) throw 1;
    *p = x;
}
catch (...) {
    int a = 0;
}
```

Obviously, the `catch` block in the above example will always be executed.